# Any suggestions on better or optimized approach that returns single row from multiple rows based on ROW_NUMBER in SFMC

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions, sql, performance, database

I have a customer data extension where customer records are saved with order numbers like this:

**CustomerOrderDE:**

| CustomerID | OrderID | OrderTotal |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 101 | $100 |
| 1 | 102 | $200 |
| 2 | 103 | $50 |
| 3 | 104 | $75 |
| 3 | 105 | $60 |

I am trying to create a query that should return unique CustomerID (if multiple rows found, return any one row - pick random one out of multiple)

This is how my destination data extension looks like:

**DestinationDE (schema of the DE where output of the query will be saved as "Update" - Note: CustomerID is the primary key)**

| Field Names | Data Type | Primary Key |
| --- | --- | --- |
| CustomerID | text | YES |
| OrderTotal | text |  |

**Desired output:**

| CustomerID | OrderTotal |  |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | $100 | <-- any random |
| 2 | $50 |  |
| 3 | $60 | <!-- any random |

**Query 1 (with sub-query approach)**

```
SELECT x.CustomerID,
x.OrderTotal
FROM 
(
SELECT a.*,
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY CustomerID ORDER BY OrderID DESC) AS rank
FROM CustomerOrderDE a) x
where x.rank = 1
```

**Query 2 (with inner join approach)**

```
SELECT a.CustomerID,
a.OrderTotal
FROM CustomerOrderDE a
inner join
(
SELECT b.*,
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY CustomerID ORDER BY OrderID DESC) AS rank
FROM CustomerOrderDE b) b
on a.OrderID = b.OrderID and a.CustomerID = b.CustomerID and rank = 1
```

**Questions:**

**1) Is there any better / optimized approach that will perform well if working with a large data set?**

**2) Is there any issue or improvement that I can make in any of these existing queries?**

Answer (score 1):

1. Since the relevant data is already available in the inner select, the join is unnecessary. Regarding performance, the camps are rather split between join vs sub-queries, until there is data to prove one is the faster on SFMC, I'll refrain from making any statements but i do personally tend to use sub-queries over joins unless i actually need a join.
2. Neither of your queries would produce a true random results since they are being sorted by OrderID. Rerunning the query would essentially produce the same records. To achieve randomness, use `ORDER BY newid()` in your sub-query/join.

```
    SELECT x.CustomerID,
    x.OrderTotal
    FROM 
    (
    SELECT a.*,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY CustomerID ORDER BY newid()) AS rank
    FROM CustomerOrderDE a) x
    where x.rank = 1
```

Comment: Hi Alex, thank you for sharing your thoughts. I just want to make sure I am following on #1 when you say _"the join is unnecessary"_, which join are you referring to in #1? Looking at the query you shared with random newid(), it seems like it is using the same approach as #1 except randomness, correct?

Comment: Unless your comment for join was for #2 approach?